# Observable instead of function angular 8 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

So i have services and there i have functions, i want to use observable instead of classic functions.

```
  export class VideoServiceService {
  videoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('videos') || '[]');
  safeURL2: string;
  safeURL: any;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  getVideos() {
    return this.videoList;
  }

  setVideo(video: object) {
    this.videoList.push(video);
    localStorage.setItem('videos', JSON.stringify(this.videoList));
  }

  deleteVideo(index: number) {
    this.videoList = this.videoList.filter(c => c.ID !== index);
    localStorage.setItem('videos', JSON.stringify(this.videoList));
  }

  getVideo(index: number) {
   return this.videoList.find(c => c.ID === index);
  }

  getURL(data: any) {
    this.safeURL2 = data.replace('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/');
    this.safeURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.safeURL2);
    return this.safeURL;
  }

}
```

I have in other components buttons that call functions, like form to add video to a list, delete video from list, edit video from list etc. 
For example: in a list component i have edit button, witch call a edit function:

```
editDialog(id: number): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddVideoFormComponent, {data: id} );
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.videoService.deleteVideo(id);
        data.id = this.index++;
        this.videoService.setVideo(data);
        this.dataSource = this.videoService.getVideos();
        this.table.renderRows();
      }
    });
  }
```

So i use classic functions here. There is no much of tutorials about this, only for HTTP but i don't need that in this case. I only need to use observable instead of function and to call it, and pass ID.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how/where you want to use observables. I assume what you want to look at are `Subject`s, but hard to know without a better description. Which function do you want replace with an observable?

Comment: if use the 'rxjs' operator **of** you get an observable, e.g. `return of([1,2,3,4])`,

Comment: I want all functions to replace with observables.

Comment: @MladenNikolić I know you think your description of the matter is clear but it's not. saying it again won't help us understand it either. please, will you be kind to add a an example of the code you would like to end up with, give us a direction

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate observable insted classic functions, for example:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
getVideo(index: number) {
  return of(this.videoList.find(c => c.ID === index));
}
```

OR

```
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
...
getVideo(index: number) {
  return new Observable((o) => {
    o.next(this.videoList.find(c => c.ID === index));
    o.complete();
  });
}
```